# How do I specify the keyserver with GPG?

Tags: linux-mint, encryption, gpg

Tutorials online say to use the option `--keyserver`, like this:

```
gpg --send-keys <keyID> --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371'
```

but `gpg` doesn't recognise the option `--keyserver`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see a difference between these two. BTW gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.12 supports and it's man page is not silent about --keyserver

Comment: @Serge the commands has  an argument `<keyID>` that isn't visible because was interpreted as an HTML tag. I suggested an edit to correct this.

Comment: @Korgan, You asked a question along with the answer. You may want create a new answer and mark as solved. [It's OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: The right thing will be: `gpg --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371' --send-keys <keyid>*` - I would not intermix switches and values

Comment: @Kanvuanza aha, I see now)

Comment: I moved the answer out of the question (and elaborated a bit as to what happened)

Answer (score 9):

GPG's command-line parsing is a bit odd:

```
gpg [--homedir dir] [--options file] [options] command [args]
```

The correct order is options, then the command, then the command's arguments, so you should do:

```
gpg --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371' --send-keys <keyID>
```

It looks like GPG will let you get away with putting the command before the options, so you can also do:

```
gpg --send-keys --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371' <keyID>
```

But the command's arguments (in this case, `<keyID>`) must be last. From the man page:

> Please remember that option as well as command parsing stops as soon as a non-option is encountered,